# How to draw using Quartz 2D to my ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, quartz-graphics

This is sort of a beginner-level question.  I have inherited an iOS project and it is implemented with a few ViewControllers with associated XIB files.  The XIB files contain various widgets that are controlled by code in the ViewControllers (which I think is the standard way of constructing an app).

However, I need to do some custom drawing (rectangles, lines, circles, text) in between the widgets, and I'd like to use the Quartz 2D library to do this.  I've never used Quartz2D, and most of the sample code I find is centered around the View, not the ViewController.

Most of it seems to do with implementing the "drawRect" method of your View.  However, my ViewController does not have a "drawRect" function, as far as I can tell.  Is there a way I can implement a "drawRect" function on my ViewController or whatever View it is controlling?

*** addendum:
I have researched and reminded myself that the operational UIView is a property of the UIViewController, and it seems like UIView is created automatically by the application and bundled together with my XIB and ViewController (I think we selected "also create XIB" when we were creating a ViewController, so the UIView is implied?).  I don't see where this default UIView instantiation occurs.  But I assume the way to draw to it is to subclass it?

If so, what is the *cleanest* way to subclass this UIView and get access to drawRect while maintaining the connection to the existing ViewController and XIB (or storyboard)?  I inherited the project and this change needs to be low-impact.

---

Thanks for any help/thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a subclass of `UIView` and override `-drawRect:` to do your custom drawing. In the xib, select the view of your view controller, go to the Identity Inspector (third tab in the right sidebar in Xcode), and replace `UIView` with your custom subclass.

[image: XCode screenshot]

Comment: Sounds perfect... but I don't quite see where to replace UIView in the identity inspector.  Perhaps because (as I maybe should've pointed out) its based on a storyboard, not a XIB (also xcode 5.1).  When I click my window within the storyboard and select the identity inspector, the first box is "Custom Class" and the Class is "ViewControllerMain" which is my custom view controller.  I don't see a place to replace UIView...

Comment: Oh wait... it's a different identity inspector when I double-click and click within storyboard.  Got it, it works.  Thanks!!